# Will this be equivalent to d(f(x))/dx?

Tags: derivatives

Just wondering if $$d(f(e^x))/d(e^x)$$ would be equivalent to $$d(f(x))/d(x)$$ and if not what could you do to it to find $$d(f(x))/d(x)$$